# Javascript Selected values appear "object object"

Tags: javascript, object, listbox

```
items = checkListBox3.GetSelectedItems();
for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
items[i].text, items[i].value;
}
alert(items);
```

I choose 3 items in my listbox so alert result is below

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Why i can not see my Id values ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Because `items` is an array of objects.

Comment: What are you doing inside the loop?

Comment: What is your for() loop supposed to do?

Comment: Within your `for` loop you don't actually do anything with the result of `items[i].text, items[i].value`.

Comment: I try to get selected values , i use "for()" because of listing, maybe i am wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that you have in your for loop:

```
items[i].text, items[i].value;
```

...doesn't actually do anything. You are not currently assigning those values to other variables or otherwise doing any processing on them. And then when you say `alert(items)` you just get a default `toString()` conversion of your `items` which produces the `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` output that you mentioned.

If all you want to do is see the value and/or text from each option in an alert try this:

```
var items = checkListBox3.GetSelectedItems(),
    msg = "";
for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 1) {
    msg += items[i].text + " (" + items[i].value + ")\n";
}
alert(msg);
```

That is, start with an empty string, `msg`, and on each iteration of the loop add to it the text and value from the current item. Then after the loop display the string.

Alternatively something like this:

```
var items = checkListBox3.GetSelectedItems();
alert( Array.prototype.map.call(items, function(item) {
          return item.text + " (" + item.value + ")";
       }).join(", ") );
```

Comment: Note that I wasn't sure if `GetSelectedItems()` returned an actual array or an array-like object, hence the `Array.prototype.map.call(items,...`. If `GetSelectedItems()` returns an actual array you could use `items.map(...`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `alert(JSON.stringify(items, '', 4));` instead.

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON